How to call termux binaries from a root shell?
Important things:

Termux binaries are in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin
Termux libraries are in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
Android binaries are in /system/bin
Android libraries are (mostly) in /system/lib64

I am trying to execute termux binaries from a root shell (on a rooted phone, after a successful "su" command). Most of them work, although they are not in the PATH.
On ordinary Linuxes, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH could do the trick. However, the so-named "ordinary linuxes" are mostly open source linux distributions based on the GNU Libc, which has a dynamic linker (named "ld.so"), which can interpret it.
However, Android binaries are using another libc, and another linker. My tests show it is in /system/bin/linker64 and it does not honor LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
So, how could I execute termux tools from a root shell, which they can find /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib if needed?

Executing /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash from root works and it links the correct libraries (from the termux lib), but how is it possible?

Android's dynamic linker does honor LD_LIBRARY_PATH / LD_PRELOAD except for setuid/setgid processes. Termux relies on them a lot including in tsu. Use strace to see what happens under the hood. Check env in root  shell.

@IrfanLatif Thanks! Strace turns setuid out. :-) If you try to strace a setuid binary, it will run without setuid.

Correct. But Termux binaries are not setuid. And why would you run a setuid binary when already on a root shell.

@IrfanLatif Correct. But, even if it honors LD_LIBRARY_PATH, termux does not set up it, yet the termux binaries can find the termux libs. Where is it wired into them?

Btw, meanwhile I just use them and they work, although it is still not clear, where they get the library path info.

You are over-complicating it. Binaries also could have hard-coded library path. Run readelf -d $(which <binary>) | grep PATH to check it. Here is a good intro.

@IrfanLatif Wow! Right! Thanks!!!

@IrfanLatif 's wonderful comments can be summarized into an answer.

Yes, Android is using the dynamic linker /system/bin/linker64. That is a different one as the ld.so.
However, both linkers are supporting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
However, termux does not need LD_LIBRARY_PATH and does not use it.
Instead, termux binaries have a hardcoded path, inserted into the linker-related binary format data structures, pointing to the termux libraries (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib). That is where linker64 first starts to look up for the libraries.
These data structures can be read out by the readelf -d $(which <binary>) command.

Thus, the simple answer is: there is nothing to do with it, termux binaries have the termux library path hardcoded into them. Only thing to do from a root shell, to put the termux binaries into the PATH variable (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin).
